# I missed Vincent before talking to Sepiroth in the Shinra Mansion. Can I still recruit him?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

I opened the safe in Shinra Mansion and talked to Sepiroth but forgot to talk to Vincent beforehand. Do I have to force an unexpected shutdown of the game or can I still recruit him?

Comment: You can still get him, although I've forgotten the exact details of when and if there is anything stopping you from returning now.

Comment: Having revisited this online, I'm fairly sure that at any point that you can return to Neibelheim (spelling?) you can recruit him.  This should be the majority of the game.

Comment: @BlackVegetable Yes, that is true. All I had to do is leave Nibelheim and re-enter it immediately and I could then recruit Vincent. Feel free to undelete your answer if you so desire :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recruit Vincent later in the game.  Worry not, you'll have a chance to come back!  (Of course, you'll miss out on his occasional comment in some story scenes so if you have a backup save you might want to recruit him.)

Comment: ...and "later in the game" actually is "as soon as you leave Nibelheim."

Comment: He's awesome, you'll definitely want to get him. Make sure you don't miss him the second time.